# Not able to send JSON data to Rest API For POST request

Tags: java, ajax, rest

Hi Guys I am trying to send JSON data using ajax method.In Back-end I have written POST method to receive the data on clicking submit button. But On clicking the submit button i am getting "HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error".

I checked with POSTMAN the code is working fine.

Below is the error which i am getting on submitting the data.

HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error

Type Exception Report

```
Message javax.json.stream.JsonParsingException: Unexpected char 97 at (line no=1, column no=2, offset=1), expecting 'u'

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception
javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.json.stream.JsonParsingException: Unexpected char 97 at (line no=1, column no=2, offset=1), expecting 'u'\r\n\torg.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:408)\r\n\torg.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:346)\r\n\torg.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:365)\r\n\torg.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:318)\r\n\torg.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:205)\r\n\torg.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)\r\n

Root Cause
javax.json.stream.JsonParsingException: Unexpected char 97 at (line no=1, column no=2, offset=1), expecting 'u'\r\n\torg.glassfish.json.JsonTokenizer.expectedChar(JsonTokenizer.java:583)\r\n\torg.glassfish.json.JsonTokenizer.readNull(JsonTokenizer.java:315)\r\n\torg.glassfish.json.JsonTokenizer.nextToken(JsonTokenizer.java:372)\r\n\torg.glassfish.json.JsonParserImpl$NoneContext.getNextEvent(JsonParserImpl.java:402)\r\n\torg.glassfish.json.JsonParserImpl.next(JsonParserImpl.java:352)\r\n\torg.eclipse.yasson.internal.JsonbRiParser.next(JsonbRiParser.java:140)\r\n\torg.eclipse.yasson.internal.Unmarshaller.getRootEvent(Unmarshaller.java:70)\r\n\torg.eclipse.yasson.internal.Unmarshaller.deserializeItem(Unmarshaller.java:58)\r\n\torg.eclipse.yasson.internal.Unmarshaller.deserialize(Unmarshaller.java:51)\r\n\torg.eclipse.yasson.internal.JsonBinding.deserialize(JsonBinding.java:45)\r\n\torg.eclipse.yasson.internal.JsonBinding.fromJson(JsonBinding.java:85)\r\n\torg.glassfish.jersey.jsonb.internal




Ajax Method Call

$('document').ready(function(){
    $("#Submit").click(function ()
            {
        var AddDetais={
            "name":$("#first_name").val(),
            "points":parseInt($("#Marks").val())
        };

        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'http://localhost:8080/StudentDetails/webapi/stduents/Add',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data:AddDetais,
            dataType:'json',
            success:function(data)
            {
                $("#Student_name").append(data["name"]);
                $("#points").append(data["points"]);
            },
            error: function (error) { // error callback 
                var errorString=JSON.stringify(error);
                alert(error);
                $('#Error').append('Error: ' + errorString);
            }

                });

});
});

API POST  Method:



    @POST
    @Path("Add")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Student setStudent(Student a)
    {
        System.out.println(" called setStudent");
        //repos.setData(a);
        return a;


Expected Result

Name: "Henry"
Marks :112
```

Comment: Can you post the error stack trace from the server.

Comment: Hi i am getting the error:

SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Jersey Web Application] in context with path [/StudentDetails] threw exception [javax.json.stream.JsonParsingException: Unexpected char 97 at (line no=1, column no=2, offset=1), expecting 'u'] with root cause
javax.json.stream.JsonParsingException: Unexpected char 97 at (line no=1, column no=2, offset=1), expecting 'u'
 at org.glassfish.json.JsonTokenizer.expectedChar(JsonTokenizer.java:583)
 at org.glassfish.json.JsonTokenizer.readNull(JsonTokenizer.java:315)

Comment: Also On UI i am geeting below error:

Exception
javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.json.stream.JsonParsingException: Unexpected char 97 at (line no=1, column no=2, offset=1), expecting 'u'\r\n\torg.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:408)\r\n\torg.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:346)
Root Cause
javax.json.stream.JsonParsingException: Unexpected char 97 at (line no=1, column no=2, offset=1), expecting

Comment: It seems that the Json you are passing to the Server has incorrect format. So server is unable to parse it. So you are getting the error. Can you check the Json before sending it to the server.

Comment: I converted the JSON into String data  and then used alert.It is coming correctly.

Comment: Can you post the controller method where this json hits..

Comment: Hi Guys the issue got resolved by converting JSON object to String format using stringify() method and passing the converted  string object to the ajax method